# Run functions on objects in RethinkDB from R

Tags: r, reql

After opening a connection between a RethinkDB database and R using the rethinker package in R, how might I alter the following ReQL code (which runs in Data Explorer of RethinkDB web admin UI) so that the query may be executed directly from R?

```
r.db('DB').table('table_name')
 .merge(function(x){
    return {x_count: x("name").count().default(0)}
  }).merge(function(y) {
    return {
      y_name: r.db("DB").table("table_name2").getAll(y_name("name2"), {index: "index_name"})
       .filter(function (z) {
          return z("z_name").contains(z("z_id"))
        }).nth(0).default({y_name: null})("yName")
    }}).eqJoin('name_t', r.db('DB').table('table_t')).default({name_t1: null})
```

For reference, the equivalent syntax for running the following ReQL code from an open connection to a rethinkDB (cn) in R is as follows:

To query the table `'table_name'` from the RethinkDB `'DB_name'` using *ReQL*:

```
r.db('DB_name').table('table_name')
```

using *R*:

```
r()$db("DB_name")$table("table_name")$run(cn)
```